# Recursive indexing to unlist a matrix

Tags: r

Consider the following vector `x` and list `s`

```
x <- c("apples and pears", "one banana", "pears, oranges, and pizza")
s <- strsplit(x, "(,?)\\s+")
```

The desired result will be the following, but please keep reading.

```
> t(sapply(s, `length<-`, 4))
#     [,1]     [,2]      [,3]    [,4]   
#[1,] "apples" "and"     "pears" NA     
#[2,] "one"    "banana"  NA      NA     
#[3,] "pears"  "oranges" "and"   "pizza"
```

That's fine, it's a good way to do it.  But R's vectorization is one its best features, and I'd like to see if I can do this with recursive indexing, that is, using only `[` subscript indexing.

**I want start with the following**, and use the row and column indices to turn the  matrix `s` into a 3x4 matrix.  So I'm calling `cbind` on the list `s`, and starting from there.

```
(cb <- cbind(s))
#      s          
# [1,] Character,3
# [2,] Character,2
# [3,] Character,4
class(cb[1])
#[1] "list"
is.recursive(cb)
#[1] TRUE
```

I've gotten this far, but now I'm struggling with the higher dimensions. Here's the first row, From here I as to unlist the rest of the matrix using the `[` and `[[` index.

```
w <- character(nrow(cb)+nrow(cb)^2)
dim(w) <- c(3,4)
w[cbind(1, 1:3)] <- cb[[1]]    
#     [,1]     [,2]  [,3]    [,4]
#[1,] "apples" "and" "pears" ""  
#[2,] ""       ""    ""      ""  
#[3,] ""       ""    ""      ""
```

At level 2 it gets more difficult. I've been doing things like this

```
> cb[[c(1,2,1), exact = TRUE]]
# Error in cb[[c(1, 2, 1), exact = TRUE]] : 
#   recursive indexing failed at level 2
> cb[[cbind(1,2,1)]]
# Error in cb[[cbind(1, 2, 1)]] : recursive indexing failed at level 2
```

Here's an example of how the indexing proceeds. I've tried all kinds of combinations of `w[[cbind(1, 1:2)]]` and alike

```
w[cbind(1, 1:3)] <- cb[[1]]
w[cbind(2, 1:2)] <- cb[[2]]
w[cbind(3, 1:4)] <- cb[[3]]
```

From the empty matrix `w`, this produces the result

```
#     [,1]     [,2]      [,3]    [,4]   
#[1,] "apples" "and"     "pears" ""     
#[2,] "one"    "banana"  ""      ""     
#[3,] "pears"  "oranges" "and"   "pizza"
```

Is it possible to use recursive indexing on all levels, so that I can unlist `cb` into an empty matrix directly from when it was a list?  i.e. put the three `w[] <- cb[[]]` lines into one.

I'm asking this because it gets to the heart of matrix structures in R. It's about learning the indexing, and not about finding an alternative solution to my problem.

Comment: What about using `library(plyr); do.call(rbind.fill.matrix, lapply(s, matrix, nrow=1))`. This goes from `s` to `m` (bypassing `cb`)

Comment: Not sure what you have against `matrix` and as `matrix`...

Comment: you can be a little cleverer: `rbind.fill.matrix(lapply(s, rbind))` works.

Comment: I don't have anything against anything.  I want to learn other things, the underlying stuff.

Comment: @RichardScriven, that doesn't bother me. I thought you want a vecorized solution, so I didn't understand hows `matrix` isn't vectorized

Comment: @DavidArenburg - because `as.matrix` is too easy.  I like a good challenge. :-)

Comment: anyone who wants to should feel to turn my variation of @MrFlick's solution into an answer if they get around to it before I do.  The need for `matrix`/`rbind` is because `rbind.fill.matrix` internally uses `matrices[] <- lapply(matrices, as.matrix)`, and `as.matrix` coerces to a column matrix by default.

Comment: @RichardScriven, just FYI, you can also get your answer from "x" if you use [my `cSplit` function](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/11380733/), like this: `cSplit(as.data.table(x), "x", "(,?)\\s+", fixed = FALSE)`, but that doesn't help you go from "cb" to your desired output.

Comment: The `cSplit` function uses matrix indexing instead of your `for` loop, but it still requires that you create an empty matrix first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `rbind.fill.matrix` function from the `plyr` package.

```
library(plyr)
rbind.fill.matrix(lapply(s, rbind))
```

This returns

```
     1        2         3       4      
[1,] "apples" "and"     "pears" NA     
[2,] "one"    "banana"  NA      NA     
[3,] "pears"  "oranges" "and"   "pizza"
```

Note that this *does* use `as.matrix` internally: `rbind.fill.matrix` calls `matrices[] <- lapply(matrices, as.matrix)`

Answer (score 3):

If you wanted to bypass the intermediary steps, you can just use [my `cSplit` function](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/11380733/), like this:

```
cSplit(as.data.table(x), "x", "(,?)\\s+", fixed = FALSE)
#       x_1     x_2   x_3   x_4
# 1: apples     and pears    NA
# 2:    one  banana    NA    NA
# 3:  pears oranges   and pizza
as.matrix(.Last.value)
#      x_1      x_2       x_3     x_4    
# [1,] "apples" "and"     "pears" NA     
# [2,] "one"    "banana"  NA      NA     
# [3,] "pears"  "oranges" "and"   "pizza"
```

Under the hood, however, that still does require creating a matrix and filling it in. It uses matrix indexing to fill in the values, so it is quite fast.

A manual approach would look something like:

```
myFun <- function(invec, split, fixed = TRUE) {
  s <- strsplit(invec, split, fixed)
  Ncol <- vapply(s, length, 1L)
  M <- matrix(NA_character_, ncol = max(Ncol),
              nrow = length(invec))
  M[cbind(rep(sequence(length(invec)), times = Ncol),
          sequence(Ncol))] <- unlist(s, use.names = FALSE)
  M
}

myFun(x, "(,?)\\s+", FALSE)
#      [,1]     [,2]      [,3]    [,4]   
# [1,] "apples" "and"     "pears" NA     
# [2,] "one"    "banana"  NA      NA     
# [3,] "pears"  "oranges" "and"   "pizza"
```

---

Speed is not everything, but it certainly should be a consideration for this type of transformation.

Here are some tests of what has been suggested so far:

```
## The manual approach
fun1 <- function(x) myFun(x, "(,?)\\s+", FALSE)

## The cSplit approach
fun2 <- function(x) cSplit(as.data.table(x), "x", "(,?)\\s+", fixed = FALSE)

## The OP's approach
fun3 <- function(x) {
  s <- strsplit(x, "(,?)\\s+")
  mx <- max(sapply(s, length))
  do.call(rbind, lapply(s, function(x) { length(x) <- mx; x }))
}

## The plyr approach
fun4 <- function(x) {
  s <- strsplit(x, "(,?)\\s+")
  rbind.fill.matrix(lapply(s, rbind))
}
```

And, for fun, here's another approach, this one using `dcast.data.table`:

```
fun5 <- function(x) {
  dcast.data.table(
    data.table(
      strsplit(x, "(,?)\\s+"))[, list(
        unlist(V1)), by = sequence(length(x))][, N := sequence(
          .N), by = sequence], sequence ~ N, value.var = "V1")
}
```

Testing is on slightly bigger data. Not very big--12k values:

```
x <- unlist(replicate(4000, x, FALSE))
length(x)
# [1] 12000

## I expect `rbind.fill.matrix` to be slow:
system.time(fun4(x))
#    user  system elapsed 
#    3.38    0.00    3.42

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(fun1(x), fun2(x), fun3(x), fun5(x))
# Unit: milliseconds
#     expr       min       lq   median       uq      max neval
#  fun1(x)  97.22076 100.8013 102.5754 107.8349 166.6632   100
#  fun2(x) 115.01466 120.6389 125.0622 138.0614 222.7428   100
#  fun3(x) 146.33339 155.9599 158.8394 170.3917 228.5523   100
#  fun5(x) 257.53868 266.5994 273.3830 296.8003 346.3850   100
```

A bit bigger data, but still not what others might consider big: 1.2M values.

```
X <- unlist(replicate(100, x, FALSE))
length(X)
# [1] 1200000

## Dropping fun3 and fun5 now, though they are very close...
## I wonder how fun5 scales further (but don't have the patience to wait)
system.time(fun5(X))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   31.28    0.43   31.76 
system.time(fun3(X))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   31.62    0.33   31.99 

microbenchmark(fun1(X), fun2(X), times = 10)
# Unit: seconds
#     expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
#  fun1(X) 11.65622 11.76424 12.31091 13.38226 13.46488    10
#  fun2(X) 12.71771 13.40967 14.58484 14.95430 16.15747    10
```

The penalty for the `cSplit` approach would be in terms of having to convert to a "data.table" and the checking of different conditions, but as your data grows, those penalties become less noticeable.